# error while creating file path in my screen recording app

Tags: android, android-studio

I am  trying to make a screen recorder app by following   [this](https://github.com/chinmoyp/screenrecorder) repo but when I runs the app its crashes with Toast :- Failed to create Recordings directory.  I don't have SDcard in my phone  please help me , I given all permission manually

My ManifestPermissions: -

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
```

my method for geting filepath :-

```
public String getFilePath() {
    final String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Recordings";
    if (!Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to get External Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    final File folder = new File(directory);
    boolean success = true;
    if (!folder.exists()) {
       success =  folder.mkdir();
    }
    String filePath;
    if (success) {
        String videoName = ("capture_" + getCurSysDate() + ".mp4");
        filePath = directory + File.separator + videoName;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create Recordings directory", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Comment: Did you request runtime permissions too? Android 10+ device?

Comment: right now I m not requesting for runtime permission , i gives permission manually....and Running device is Android pie

Comment: Your function getFileParh() looks ok. And there is no reason why you would post all that mainactivity code. Please remove.

Comment: You are talking about an error and a message "Failed ..". But there is no error. And that is your own message. What happens is that mkdir() returns false. You did not mention mkdir(). Not in subject. Nor in your post.

Comment: why mkdir returning false ?

Comment: It could not create that directory.

Comment: problem is why it not creating that directory ..what wrongs here?

Comment: I have no idea. Your code should work. Try other devices and emulators.